# Possible to filter REST API Queries endpoint?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I'm doing a spot check right now to see if any queries are using a specific DE. What qualifies as using a specific DE is if they mention my target DE's name in a query, or the query saves to that target DE.

I know this queries endpoint exists:

```
automation/v1/queries
```

and the response I'm getting back will look something like this:

```
        {
            "queryDefinitionId": "id here",
            "name": "Journey name",
            "key": "key here",
            "description": "Get all the Subscribers for 180 journey",
            "queryText": "sql query here",
            "targetName": "target de name",
            "targetKey": "target key name",
            "targetDescription": "",
            "createdDate": "2019-09-13T14:27:51.507",
            "modifiedDate": "2019-12-04T13:52:49.337",
            "targetUpdateTypeId": 0,
            "targetUpdateTypeName": "Overwrite",
            "categoryId": 49451,
            "isFrozen": false
        }
```

I am able to add a filter for name, but when I try to filter on targetKey/targetname/queryText, I'm getting this message:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Filter is invalid, identifier 'targetkey' not allowed"
        }
    ]
}
```

In theory it would've been great to spot check and see what queries mentioned my target de (by filtering queryText) as well as finding queries that target the same de.

Anyone have any other ideas how I can approach this? There's quite a bit of query activities so it's not feasible for me to mill through each one to see if it contains the target DE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately as this is an undocumented and unofficially supported endpoint, the abilities for filtering and other similar capabilities are limited. I believe this endpoint can only be filtered on Name.

To my knowledge there is no way to filter this from the response. You would have to pull the full JSON and then use an **[array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** (see below backfill) or a similar function to sift through your returned JSON for the relevant results.

Backfill:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach = function(c) {
  if (c && {}.toString.call(c) === '[object Function]') {
    f = c;
    var a;
    for(i=0;i<this.length;i++) {
      f(this[i])       
    }
  } else {
     return {"Error": "Filter provided is not a function"};
  }
}
```

or a function similar to this:

```js
function search(nameKey, myArray){
    for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].name === nameKey) {
            return myArray[i];
        }
    }
}

var array = [
    { name:"string 1", value:"this", other: "that" },
    { name:"string 2", value:"this", other: "that" }
];

var resultObject = search("string 1", array);
```

(function taken from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)** )